# Command-line Resource Monitor for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, resource-monitor

On Windows, there's a GUI "Task Manager", and there's also a great little command-line "tasklist.exe" which lets me see most of the same data but in text that's really easy to parse from a script.

Is there an analogous command-line tool for "Resource Monitor"?  I'm looking for something that will list global CPU/disk/network/memory usage, and/or per-process usage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for [typeperf](//docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf). It should work for:

- Windows Server 2003 - 2016
- Windows 10
- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows XP

An example:

```sh
typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

will log the processor time until you hit Ctrl-C. Adding `-sc 5` will report 5
instances:

```sh
typeperf -sc 5 "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

Here is example for disk activity, total bytes per second:

```sh
typeperf -si 2 "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Bytes/sec"
```

[Windows Performance Monitor Disk Counters Explained](//blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to look into [`pslist`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682).

It doesn't provide everything you're looking for. But it's the only CLI tool I know that at least provide some of it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Just launch Run:

```
WinKey + R
```

type:

```
resmon
```

and press

```
OK
```

Comment: How does this different from the existing answer that describes the exact same process?

Comment: It is a shortcut to access the Resource Monitor from the Run window rather then the CLI. It is an alternative answer to the original question and with a direct access to the Resource Monitor, without the need to go through the Task Manager as answered by Tom. Different way, same results. ;)

Comment: You do understand that typing `resmon` in a run prompt is going to launch resmon.exe just like typing `cmd` will launch the command prompt.

Comment: One of the answers correctly suggests going through the CLI (Command Line Interface aka command prompt) and the other suggests going through the run prompt and task manager. Mine suggests going through the prompt directly to the resmon. It might be opening the same program but it is a different step. My answer is  what I was looking for and is here future reference.

Answer (score 1):

**resmon.exe** is the "resource monitor" ordinarily launched from the taskmgr.

The path to **resmon.exe** is processor specific, but there's usually a copy for your processor in ...\windows\system32 or ...\windows\system

(You can launch the task manager by ctrl-alt-del, or by typing "tskmgr" at a command line or at "Run ..." in the start menu)

last verified on Win7

Comment: What do you mean by "processor specific"?

Comment: I think he means "operating specific", as in what version of Windows (and what edition) you're using.

Answer (score -2):

Monitoring your computer’s Internet activity is a powerful tool, enabling you to:

- Keep an eye on background processes
- Reveal viruses and other malware
- Expose unauthorized access
- Monitor running programs
- Log process activity

..and much more.

The best part? It’s super-easy. Here’s how I do it on Windows XP:

Open the `cmd` and type `netstat -n 5 >scan.txt`
After a minute or two (or any amount of time), press Ctrl+C to stop monitoring. Type `scan.txt` to open the log file and check the results
There are many ways to modify the log output using various parameters. Here are a couple of alternate commands you can try:

`netstat -b 5 >scan.txt` or `netstat -nao 5 >scan.txt`
The second one also provides PID (Process ID) numbers that may be verified against running processes in the Windows Task Manager (under View > Select Column..). Feel free to terminate any processes running unwanted TCP connections. For a complete list of netstat parameters, type `netstat help` in the command prompt.

Here’s how I do it on Mac OSX:

Open Terminal, and type `netstat -b >> scan.txt`
After a minute or two (or any amount of time), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop monitoring.
Type `more scan.txt` to open the log file and check the results.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using **Windows**.